# How to you install Adobe Air on Loki 64bit

Tags: macbook

I've tried following other guides for Ubuntu on this, but no dice.  I keep getting this error after running

sudo ./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin

error:
/tmp/air.7AG64G/setup: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

When i followed all the other guides to install required libraries, it can't find anything!  I'm running on a live USB on a macbook air 2014

Comment: why do you need adobe air?, if you check Adobe's page it says that isn't supported anymore in linux

Comment: I'm setting up a USB stick for my 8 year old son so he can just Scratch programming offline, which requires Adobe Air unfortunately...

Comment: Hey Craig, would you please write up your solution as an answer so other searchers can benefit from your research in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after much effort, I finally got this to work.  Here's how:

```
sudo apt-get -f install

sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

sudo apt-get install libxt6:i386 libnspr4-0d:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libnss3-1d:i386 libxml2:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 gtk2-engines-murrine:i386
```

Note: the above command is similar to other tutorials, but without `lib32nss-mdns:i386` as it couldn't be found.  This was a huge PIA and a lot of googling to find the answer, so the replacement can be installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install libnss-sss:i386
```

Then, as with other tutorials, create the symbolic links with:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0 /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0
```

and

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0 /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0
```

Then finally, make the Adobe installer executable with:

```
sudo chmod a+x AdobeAIRInstaller.bin
```

Then install it:

```
sudo ./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin
```

Now, it takes some time for the dialog to show after the above command, so give it a while.  But when finished, you should see Adobe Air in your applications.

Then for completeness, delete the symbolic links with

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0
```

and

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0
```

So after all that, I tried to install Scratch 2.0 Offline (which was the whole point of the exercise) and it didn't work!  Then I changed the permissions of the .air file to full read write execute for both current user and sudo and voila, it worked!

Answer (score -1):

Try this tutorial, it should work

http://www.noobslab.com/2015/05/adobeair-is-now-available-for-ubuntu.html

Comment: Tried that on eOS Loki, no dice, says script is only for Ubunut x.xx etc

Comment: Also tried "sudo dpkg --add-infrastructure i386" then when I run the Adobe installer again, I get an error relating to libstdc++

Comment: From further research it seems I need the ia386-libs, but alas it still wont install!!!  Anyone know a manual way I can do that?

Comment: Try downloading it from here http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/ia32-libs

Comment: huzzaaah!!  Did a "sudo apt-get -f install" then ran the Adobe Air binary

Comment: Update: Air installed as above (but I feel like I've had to install a heap of bloat that isn't needed), but when I try to install Scratch 2.0, it says that something else is installing and must finish first.  Oh I do so hate Adobe Air!!!  I wish someone would fork Scratch and make a native linux app :)